# json.success redirect to thank you page

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this code in one of my PHP templates.

```
// IF successful hide the form and show thanks

if (json.success) {
    $('#payment-form').hide();
    $('#thank-you').show();
}
```

If I would like to redirect to `thank-you.php` instead of showing #thank-you is it possible with this code or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to new page by changing `location.href` property:

```
if (json.success) {
    location.href = '/thank-you.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if (json.success) {
   window.location.href = 'thank-you.php';
}
```